# How i can get formula for find Determinant of matrix 4n?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I how find determint through formula, but i only find formula for 3x3 matrix. 
$a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}-a_{11}a_{23}a_{32}-a_{12}a_{21}a_{33}+a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}+a_{13}a_{21}a_{32}-a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}$

Comment: You can use cofactor expansion to write out the determinant, but it's a LOT longer ($4!=24$ terms).  It's really not worth the time unless you're coding it.

Comment: There is a general formula as a sum of products of permutations ([Leibniz Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants))

Comment: Use [Laplace's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace.27s_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix). Or (numerically better) compute the $LU$-decomposition, or any other decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use [Laplace's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion). In general, it is not a good idea to memorize formulas for determinants. If you understand how to apply Laplace's formula just calculate the determinant recursively.

You can also use Leibniz Formula as Tob Ernack proposed, but in general, it will be more time-consuming to calculate the determinant by that procedure.